# Slow delete of CoreData objects

Tags: core-data

I'm trying out CoreData for pretty much the first time, believe it or not.

I will have about 10000 objects of an entity A.

Sometimes I will need to replace all those objects with new ones, about the same amount. Deleting all entities takes a long long time, so I looked around and some people seemed to suggest that if we create a "collection" object that contains all of the other objects, we can just delete the collection and then have Core Data cascade delete the other objects.
I haven't been able to do any exact time check so far but it does not feel like this changes anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: Always delete everything and start over?

Comment: You mean I should just update the existing stuff? That sounds more complicated.

Comment: No, it's a question, will you always be deleting everything or sometimes only deleting 90% for example. And does the data store only contain these entities or other things that are not being deleted?

Comment: I delete everything. The "A" entities also have "B" in relations to them, i have those cascade delete too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to tear down your Core Data stack and then delete the data store from disk (preferably by using the persistent store coordinator `removePersistentStore:error:`. This only works if you are deleting everything. Afterwards you rerun your code to setup the Core Data stack.

If you need to delete manually then you should batch save the context and you will need to profile to find the best batch size.

Comment: Ok I thought about that but it doesn't really feel like a kosher thing to do... well, if in case I would like to keep other things in the same data store in the future.

Comment: Then you have a judgement call about what you're doing, potentially splitting the data store into parts, potentially deleting things in the background while allowing the user to carry on in the foreground. There is no one answer (certainly without knowing your full situation and likely future direction).